# How do I insert and query a DateTime object in SQLite DB from C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, ado.net

Consider this snippet of code:

```
string sDate = string.Format("{0:u}", this.Date);

           Conn.Open();
            Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TRADES VALUES(" + "\"" + this.Date + "\"" + "," +this.ATR + "," + "\"" + this.BIAS + "\"" + ")";
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note the "this.Date" part of the command. Now Date is an abject of type DateTime of C# environment, the DB doesnt store it(somewhere in SQLite forum, it was written that ADO.NET wrapper automatically converts DateTime type to ISO1806 format)

But instead of this.Date when I use sDate (shown in the first line) then it stores properly.

My probem actually doesnt end here. Even if I use "sDate", I have to retrieve it through a query. And *that is creating the problem*

Any query of this format

```
SELECT * FROM <Table_Name> WHERE DATES = "YYYY-MM-DD"
```

returns nothing, whereas replacing '=' with '>' or '<' returns right results.

So my point is:

**How do I query for Date variables from SQLite Database.**

**And if there is a problem with the way I stored it (i.e non 1806 compliant), then how do I make it compliant**

Comment: Which SQLite library are you using?

Comment: System.Data.SQLite, the ADO.NET wrapper for SQLite

Comment: there are several ADO.NET wrappers for SQLite. System.Data.SQLite is the most common, but other wrapper providers would be offended if you call it "the" ADO.NET wrapper.

Comment: @Sam, my bad, I was not clear on that front

Answer (score 5):

The ADO.NET wrapper can't convert the DateTime values to ISO 8601 (not [1806](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=28360)) if you convert it to a string and put it in the query. You need to use parameters for that:

```
Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TRADES VALUES (@Date, @Atr, @Bias)";
Command.Parameters.Add("@Date", this.Date);
Command.Parameters.Add("@Atr", this.ATR);
Command.Parameters.Add("@Bias", this.BIAS);
Conn.Open();
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(Besides, you converted the DateTime value to a string and put in the sDate variable, but then you used the DateTime value to produce the SQL query anyway.)

The same applies when getting the data:

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM <Table_Name> WHERE DATES = @Date";
Command.Parameters.Add("@Date", theDate);
```

Comment: Yes, I was just showing the alternative. I did write and check with this.Date as well as sDate.

SDate works, this.Date doesnt.

Thanks Guffa, I think perhaps the problem is solved, let me plug it in and check

Answer (score 2):

About your second problem, if SQLite is anything close to SQL Server,

SELECT * From  where Dates = "YYYY-MM-DD' will not return because it will probably implicitily convert YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00. You might need to add a range (e.g. greater or equal than today and smaller than tomrrow).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't got this explicitly enough. When I said SQLite is anything close to SQL Server I mean from a Query Language point of view. I didn't touch SQLite before, and I'm conscious that other flavours of SQL can have differences in how they execute basic command.

Answer (score 0):

@Guffa, I am getting "Cannot Convert from System.DateTime to System.Data.DbType" on this line:

Command.Parameters.Add("@Date", this.Date);

Comment: There are some different overloads for creating parameters. Check the documentation for what's available, and preferrably use an overload where you can specify the data type, something like: `Command.Parameters.Add("@Date", DbType.DateTime).Value = this.Date;`